# Which java version should I use in Android Studio to build an app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Which java version should I use in android projects, I know by default android set target and compiler version to JAVA 1.8, but gradle sdk is set to java 11 by default. And In somewhere in compose documentation I see we can use java 17 for target and compile options. I just want to know how and from where I can check latest supported java version in android because I want to use latest java version. Reason for that is newer version comes with new features that' why. I

Answer (score 6):

Please see [Java versions in Android builds](https://developer.android.com/build/jdks). (Disclosure: I wrote it)

The main place Google keeps the info for which Java levels are supported is [Which Java APIs can I use in my Java or Kotlin source code?](https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#compileSdk)

The Android `compileSdk` determines which JDK API are available for use in your source code (Kotlin or Java).

Be aware that there are multiple JDKs in play:

- **JDK that runs Android Studio** - let it default to the JetBrains Runtime (JBR) that comes with Android Studio
- **JDK that runs Gradle** - set it in Android Studio for Studio builds or via `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`, which defaults to `JAVA_HOME`, for shell builds
- **Toolchain JDK** - default for source and target levels, as well as JDK used to run unit tests. I *strongly* recommend using this instead of `sourceCompatibility`, `targetCompatibility` and `jvmTarget`. Set by adding

  ```kotlin
  kotlin {
     jvmToolchain(17)
  }
  ```

  at the top of your module's `build.gradle.kts`, and remove `sourceCompatibility`, `targetCompatibility` and `jvmTarget` settings.
- **`sourceCompatibility`** - Java level for Java source (defaults to toolchain)
- **`targetCompatibility`** - Java bytecode generation level for Java source (defaults to toolchain)
- **`jvmTarget`** - Java bytecode generation level for Kotlin source (defaults to toolchain)

Answer (score 0):

For the Java version use for development and compilation, it depends on the `minSdkVersion` of your app.

Yeah, you can use a JDK that is recent to build, but the `minSdkVersion` set a limit to *Java runtime and API* present on your device.

Case of using `Iterator` in project targeting `minSdkVersion 21`
[image: Higher API CALL]

Table

| Android | Java | API & language features supported |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 (API 34) | 17 | Core libraries |
| 13 (API 33) | 11 | Core libraries |
| 12 (API 32) | 11 | Java API |
| API 24 | 8 | Android versions |
| API 10 (not sure) | 7 | Android versions |

That's why, I switched to Kotlin, to have a more advanced language without the cons of `minSdkVersion`.
In Java 'old-fashioned', it's more velocity in code writing !

See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/jdks)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the doc page. I wrote it a couple of months ago and it's great to see that it's useful! Note that desugaring should take care of minSdk issues - see [Java 8+ API desugaring support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring). (Feel free to add to your answer). And kudos on the Kotlin advice! Great language!

Comment: @ScottStanchfield Oh, didn't know about the Java 8+ API Desugaring, Thanks. But I didn't understand why the 'Java-Runtine' on the 20-30 Sdk didn't update to the latest Java LTS Version like Java 11. Then I know Covid disrupt Android API release. I'm fine, that they updated it for the next APIs, hopefully, they will follow the "new" rhythm of JDK's release.